# Geoserver Extension access restriction with proxy nginx

Tags: geoserver, proxy, geoserver-rest-api

I have installed Geoserver on my server. And I have proxy server(installed nginx) to access Geoserver.

```
location /geoserver {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/geoserver/;
}
```

`http://mydomain.com/geoserver` ==> to ==>    `http://localhost:8080/geoserver`

I installed geoserver extensions (Shape, Excel, DXF) that users can download geographic data.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetFeature&typeName=Polygons&BBOX=-103.929,44.375,-103.633,44.500&outputFormat=dxf
```

But someone can download all geographic data in a city of BBOX . I want to restrict access download. How can I do this with proxy server or other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "someone can download all geographic data. I want to restrict access download."

If you want to allow only some people the ability to download the given data, there are a couple of ways to do this.

- You can either use GeoServer's comprehensive built in Security components to only allow access to authorised individuals. - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html#sec-layer
- Or of you want to do it proxy side (with nginx), you'd probably be better off asking at the sister site: https://www.serverfault.com/

Of course, the nature of WFS is that it is inherently a data-download service. If you don't want that functionality at all then disable WFS.

You can also use layer control to specify which layers are downloadable themselves too.

Finally, you may wish to limit the number of responses WFS supplies. This is done through the service admin panel - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/services/WFS.html#features

Comment: I updated question. I mean someone can download my all data that specify a BBOX.

Comment: @barteloma - I'm not 100% what you want. You want people to only be able to download data within a specified BBOX? Or excluding a BBOX? Either way, I don't believe GeoServer has the ability to do that. I guess you could write a custom rule for the proxy to intercept and parse all queries, but that would probably be very processing heavy.